# Streaming big JSON files using big-json

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I am trying to write "big" JSON objects to file.

I'm using the library 'big-json'. The code is working mostly fine and 90% of the times it writes a 400kb JSON file that can be read in again.

Sometimes however the 'end' event is never called and the stream appends data indefinitely. Leading to very big files ~300MB with invalid JSON.

I tried to debug the content of the file to see if there's a hint to an error with my code, but to no avail.

The code is as follows.

```js
class MemoryStore {
  store = () => {
    const fn = path.resolve(this._options.file);
    if (this._storing) return;
    this._storing = true;
    if (this._options.logger) {
      this._options.logger.info`Serializing store to ${fn}`;
    }

    if (fs.existsSync(fn)) {
      fs.copyFileSync(fn, fn + '.bak');
      fs.unlinkSync(fn);
    }

    const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(fn);
    const stream = this.serialize();
    stream.pipe(writeStream);

    stream.on('end', () => {
      if (this._options.logger) {
        this._options.logger.info`Serialized store to ${fn}`;
      }
      writeStream.end();
      this._storing = false;
    });
    writeStream.on('error', (err) => {
      writeStream.end();
      this._storing = false;
    });
  };

  serialize = () => {
    const { _options: _, ...rest } = this;
    const states = [...this._states.entries()];
    const scopes = [...this._scopes.entries()].map(([key, value]) => {
      return [key, [...value.entries()]];
    });
    const out = { _scopes: scopes, _states: states };
    return json.createStringifyStream({
      body: out,
    });
  };

}
```

Comment: Can you reshape your output into a list of state and scope? It might be much easier to stream that.

Comment: @JonSG That will be difficult as they are independent. I could maybe stream arrays of states and scopes into different files.

Comment: sorry, I assumed that they were paired.

Comment: The only idea I have is that the object is being mutated while exporting leading to some sort of infinite loop bug. But that seems a bit far-fetched. I will try and deep-clone the object before exporting it. Maybe this fixes this behaviour

Comment: Any reason why you're using a giant JSON file and not a database?

Comment: @kelsny It's part of my own framework. The memory store doesn't connect to a database but offers serialization. In case you need to persist data across server restarts without requiring a database. There's also a transport to postgres. It's not meant to be a replacement for a db.

Comment: Hm. Well it sounds like you should use Redis for this instead... As you know, it's meant for this kind of thing.

Comment: @kelsny I know, I'll add a redis transport as well. I still want to solve this bug.

Comment: Doesn't `pipe` forward the `end` event automatically? (Or was there an option to do that?). Apart from that detail, there's nothing obviously wrong with your code, I think you should report this as a bug with the *big-json* library.